# sql loader does not insert all records without any errors in log in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I try to insert 100 millions records of 18 fields on scv file(15G) in oracle by sql loader but 89 million records inserted and others not without any errors in log. I set all field to char type in sql loader file control and oracle tables to handle conflict data type. this my clt file

```
option (skip=1, parallel=true, errors=5000)
load data
characterset  UTF8
infile 'file.scv'
append
into table table_name
fields terminated by ','
trailling nullcols(
name char(200),
family char(200)
...
)
```

sql loader command is

```
sqlldr userid=user/pas@ip:port/sid 
DATA=file_name.csv table=table_name log=log_file_name.log
```

and my table space options are, size 77.2G, auto extend true, max size unlimited.
why this happen? is it about memory capacity or other options in oracle or sql loader?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is you who instructed SQL*Loader to do that.

```
option (skip=1, parallel=true, errors=5000)
                               -----------
```

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm#g1014550) says:

> ERRORS specifies the maximum number of insert errors to allow. If the number of errors exceeds the value specified for ERRORS, then SQL*Loader terminates the load. To permit no errors at all, set ERRORS=0. To specify that all errors be allowed, use a very high number.

You allowed *5000*. What happened then? As Oracle says, **SQL*Loader terminated the load**.

Check the `.BAD` file for more info.

Comment: thanx. my problem is that csv file has a end of file character middle of file and sql* loader stop reading file.

Comment: @r.a.shehni - WHY does your file have an end-of-file character in the middle of the file? If you can find it, remove it (unless it is there for a good reason).

Comment: unfortunately, I do not create csv file so I think this a mistake in create. I test file with a python code and found that.